# want to show admob interstitial on app start

Tags: android, admob

I integrate the interstitial ad from admob in my application and that is of google play version. I want to show ad on starting of app but it does not work. I have a code in which ad comes up on "onPause", "onResume" etc methods. Is there any way to show ad on starting of app like within 2 second of starting an app.
Here is my code for interstitial.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StartAppAd.init(this, "110342272", "204516610");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2869508995487312/2690564381");

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
           }
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
display();
super.onStart();
}

public void display() {
if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
interstitial.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's what I created to  load interstitial ad when user open the app:

```
      InterstitialAd interstitial;

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID";
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);


    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);

    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Yes this helped me out. Nice solution.

Answer (score 13):

According to new policies of Admob , interstitial ads are not permitted on start and exiting of app.Your account may be banned if you will violate this policy. Therefore avoid it. Please click on the following link to read the admob policy for more clarification.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en

Comment: Very important tip for new comers, as this question is the first that pops up when you google it

Answer (score 0):

According to https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en you can show ads on app start as long as you've loaded the app before showing it.

insert this member variable `private val doOnce = true`

**doOnce** will ensure that your Ad is shown only once when the ad is Loaded, since onAdLoaded is a callback failure to do this will cause incessant spam ad popups.

```
mInterstitialAd?.adListener = object : AdListener() {
   override fun onAdClosed() {
      requestNewInterstitial()
   }

   override fun onAdLoaded() {
      super.onAdLoaded()
      if (doneOnce) {
         mInterstitialAd?.show()
         doneOnce = false
       }
   }
}
```

Save and retrieve it across configuration change

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
   outState?.putBoolean(DO_ONCE_KEY, doOnce)
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
   if (savedInstanceState != null){
       doOnce = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(DO_ONCE_KEY)
   }
}
```